# Json value interpretation

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
"markers": [
    {
        "status": "gone",
        "title": "HOWRAH JN (HWH)",
        "lat": "22.58405800",
        "lng": "88.34097900"
    },
    {
        "status": "gone",
        "title": "ASANSOL JN (ASN)",
        "lat": "23.69110100",
        "lng": "86.97481200"
    },
    {
        "status": "current",
        "title": "JAMTARA (JMT)",
        "lat": "23.95927400",
        "lng": "86.80555300"
    },
    {
        "status": "yettocome",
        "title": "MADHUPUR JN (MDP)",
        "lat": "24.27075300",
        "lng": "86.64230300"
    },
    {
        "status": "yettocome",
        "title": "JASIDIH JN (JSME)",
        "lat": "24.51479700",
        "lng": "86.64453500"
    },
    {
        "status": "yettocome",
        "title": "JHAJHA (JAJ)",
        "lat": "24.77917600",
        "lng": "86.39957400"
    }
]
```

I want to get the only first value of "title" after "current". For example, I need to echo "title": "MADHUPUR JN (MDP)" i.e the first value of "status": "yettocome" . Here Is my code:

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i<count($array['markers']); $i++) { 
    if($array['markers'] [$i]['status'] == "yettocome") { 
        echo $array['markers'][$i]['title']; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: there is a whitespace in the line: "$array['markers'] [$i]['status']" between ['markers'] and [$i]

Comment: Okay fine! Though It's printing all the title values which is equivalent to "yettocome". But I need only the 1st value i.e " title:" "Madhupur Jn". Any help?

Comment: Thankyou! It worked. @ctwheels

Comment: You're very welcome. I've moved my comment to an answer so that it can be easier to find for other users.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop will loop over all values of the array.
The `break` statement will end the `foreach` loop's execution when it's reached.
I, personally, find that `foreach` loops keep code a little neater than `for` loops (especially with your use case).

```
foreach($array['markers'] as $marker){
    if($marker['status'] === 'yettocome') {
        echo $marker['title'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the whitespace in `$array['markers'] [$i]['status']` between `['markers']` and `[$i]`.

Comment: I need the 1st value not all values.